# SQL query: calculate profile or loss in given 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables storing income:

```
id    name     date         price     isDel
1     abc     2012-01-26    613.90       0
2     cde     2012-01-25    530.10       0
```

and expenses:

```
id     name   price    date         isDel
1      b1     334.90   2012-01-26   0
2      b1     41.90    2012-01-25   0
3      d1     61.90    2012-01-25   0
```

I would like to get the result as follows:

```
date        total income         total expense             profile n loss
2012-01-25  530.10                103.80                    426.30
2012-01-26  613.90                344.90                    26.90
```

Thanks. Can anyone provide SQL solutions? I did refer some member's question and answer at stackoverflow but I can't modify to want I need. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Provided you want profit/loss per day this should do:

```
SELECT Inc.date, TotalInc, TotalExp, TotalInc - TotalExp AS ProfitNLoss
FROM
(
  SELECT date, SUM(price) as TotalInc
  FROM Income
  WHERE isdel = 0
  GROUP BY date) as Inc
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(

  SELECT date, SUM(price) as TotalExp
  FROM Expense
  WHERE isdel = 0
  GROUP BY date) as Exp

ON Inc.date = Exp.date

UNION

SELECT Exp.date, TotalInc, TotalExp, TotalInc - TotalExp AS ProfitNLoss
FROM
(
  SELECT date, SUM(price) as TotalInc
  FROM Income
  WHERE isdel = 0
  GROUP BY date) as Inc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
(

  SELECT date, SUM(price) as TotalExp
  FROM Expense
  WHERE isdel = 0
  GROUP BY date) as Exp

ON Inc.date = Exp.date
```

Comment: Thanks Pheiberg, i got your advice on my code, let me see if i could enhance a bit while either income or expense has no record its not return to NULL, Like 0 so that the calculation still working.

Comment: HI Pheiberg, i had added IFNULL(TotalInc,0)[note: im using MySql] and ect.So now it works if table and no records of return NULL and profit still calculated. Thanks

Comment: @user994985 - If you feel an answer was correct you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Argh, this is "give me the codes" question, but I'll give you few hints:

- [mySQL GROUP BY tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)
- [mySQL GRUOP BY aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
- [mySQL subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

So what you need to do:

Create list of all unique dates (unfortunately I haven't find a way to generate list of dates within sql without table query or without long php array, if anyone knows a way to do this I'll be glad to add it to anser), so you will have to do this:

```sql
SELECT date FROM income GROUP BY date;
-- If there's a chance that you'll have record in expenses and not in income:
(SELECT date FROM income GROUP BY date)
    UNION (SELECT date FROM expenses GROUP BY date;)
    GROUP BY date;
-- Or create table containing just list of all dates (best option)
```

And than join all unique dates with expenses and income:

```sql
SELECT SUM(expenses.price) AS expenses, SUM(incomes.price) AS income, dates.date
    FROM unique_dates -- or from your subquery
    LEFT JOIN incomes ON incomes.date = unique_dates.date
    LEFT JOIN expenses ON expenses.date = unique_dates.date
    GROUP BY unique_dates.date
```

*Oh and I have no idea what does `profile n loss` mean.*

Comment: HI Vyktor, thanks for your advise, maybe im dump on sql, i will keep me learning. BTW the Union seem working well for my question. Maybe u can make use of it instate of create another date table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pheiberg and appreciated for your prof reply. 
I just did some little change so it will return 0 when table has no record or return NULL, So that Profit calculation still able to cal even given -ve value. Here the code share to u guys.

note: im using MySQL

```
SELECT Inc.create_dt, IFNULL(TotalInc,0), IFNULL(TotalExp,0), IFNULL(TotalInc,0) - IFNULL(TotalExp,0) AS ProfitNLoss
FROM
(
  SELECT create_dt, SUM(price) as TotalInc
  FROM income
  WHERE IsDel= 0
  GROUP BY create_dt) as Inc
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT create_dt, SUM(price) as TotalExp
  FROM expenses
  WHERE IsDel= 0
  GROUP BY create_dt) as Exp

ON Inc.create_dt= Exp.create_dt
UNION
SELECT Exp.create_dt, IFNULL(TotalInc,0), IFNULL(TotalExp,0), IFNULL(TotalInc,0) - IFNULL(TotalExp,0) AS ProfitNLoss
FROM
(
  SELECT create_dt, SUM(price) as TotalInc
  FROM income
  WHERE IsDel= 0
  GROUP BY create_dt) as Inc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT create_dt, SUM(price) as TotalExp
  FROM expenses
  WHERE IsDel= 0
  GROUP BY create_dt) as Exp
ON Inc.create_dt= Exp.create_dt
```